# Using rsync to sync new files from windows folder to ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, mount, windows-7, rsync

I am trying to backup my photos from my windows computer to my ubuntu server. But each time I run rsync it transfers all the files each time. I have researched how to modify the rsync command, but I have yet to find anything that works.

This is how I mount the windows folder in fstab:

```
//WIN/share /media/windowsshare cifs credentials=/home/jason/Documents/win.credentials,sec=ntlmssp
```

This is my rsync command:

```
rsync -h -v -r -P -t -O --ignore-existing /media/windowsshare/photos /media/mediadisk1/data/photos
```

I have also tried adding `--size-only` and `--checksum` to the rsync command because I read in a post that Ubuntu's timestamp is different than windows and that can cause syncing problems, but those did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo rsync --archive --verbose --human-readable --itemize-changes --progress --no-o --no-g --delete --delete-excluded /media/windowsshare/photos /media/mediadisk1/data/photos 2>&1 | tee -a /home/XXX/rsync-output.txt
```

On location `/home/XXX/rsync-output.txt` command will create log file and you can see what is done.